# How can we define null as a datatype in Android, like we define nsNull in iPhone

Tags: android, json, types, null

`jsonObject.accumulate("status",null);`

I want to pass null as a value in json service call i try `""`,`" "`, `NULL`, `nil`,`"null"` but nothing helps

Could anyone have solution for this ?

Comment: jsonObject.accumulate("usertype", 1);
                jsonObject.accumulate("Userid", LoginActivity.user_id);
                jsonObject.accumulate("isSaved", true);
                jsonObject.accumulate("buyerId", 0);
                jsonObject.accumulate("status",null);
                jsonObject.accumulate("OrderNo",null);           in above json service call i want to pass null in "status" & "OrderNo".

Answer (score 6):

> Try using `JSONObject.NULL` instead of null, if you are using org.json.

Referenced from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#NULL).

**edit**

I tried, creating an json object with null as value, something like this.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("Test", JSONObject.NULL);
```

and the output generated on printing it was, `{"Test": null}`

So, I guess this will do the magic for you. :)

Comment: JSONObject.Null is used for checking  json object is null or not or i think its usefull at retriving time but i m trying to call .net service and at that time i want to pass null as a parameter.

Comment: it will probably set value as "null". What are you expecting on server side?

Comment: server side i m expecting null without "null" double quotes its like null data type

Comment: "usertype" : "1",
  "buyerId" : 0,
  "isSaved" : true,
  "Userid" : 60,
  "OrderNo" : null,
  "ip" : "192.168.137.6",
  "status" : null, ......................see this is my iphone service call exactly i want like this null but want be able to send like this when i call services it will automatically remove those parameter which define as null.

Comment: good news.. when you use JSONObject.NULL, it creates json like `{"Test": null}`. Just Tested. So now your .net server can easily convert it to its own null reference.

Comment: ohhhhh thanxxx a lot dude finally i found solution ....thank you very much now its working good.... :)